# Adding application to manifest: attribute Android: name is not allowed here

Tags: android

I'm trying to add an application to my manifest but I receive and error: `attribute Android: name is not allowed here`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.test.app" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.test.app.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

    <application
        android:name="com.test.app.connection.AppController" <--- problem
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- all activities and other stuff -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can only use single application tag in your manifest

Comment: @Karl Morrison  I had the problem similar with yours. The problem comes when I import the project from **Eclipse** to **IntelliJ**. (well, this is a really crazy matter issue for me recently cause there're so many strange problems will comes when I import the project from **Eclipse/Android Studio** to **IntelliJ**, although they have same settings)  And, I only have one **application** and all tags are set properly. Have you ever fixed it out? Maybe I need  your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> attribute Android: name is not allowed here

Because you are trying to add `application` tag inside `application` tag which is not allowed in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Only single `application` tag is allowed which will contains other application components like Activities, Services, BroadcastReceiver,...

So remove second `application` tag and add all attribute like `name`,`icon`,... in single  `application` :

```
 <application
        android:name="com.test.app.connection.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <!-- add application components here -->
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

you can only have one Application Tag for your Application as demonstrated above,try to use android documentation as much as you can! Best!

Answer (score 0):

add android:name attribute to the existing application tag in the manifest file

```
android:name="com.test.app.connection.AppController"
```